# Add Record in form using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

currently I am working on angularjs and I am beginner to the angular.
I am trying to make a form which have an create button which create a record on server using service.
Angular code is:

```
$scope.createNewRecord = function (record) {   
    var data = {
        "totalBudget": record.budget,
        "campaignId": record.name,
        "updateUser": null,
        "updateTime": 0,
        "advertiserId": record.advertiseId,
        "deleted": false,
        "createTime": new Date(),
        "budgetSpent": record.pricing,
        "name": null,
        "startTime": record.startTime,
        "createUser": null,
        "id": null,
        "endTime": record.endTime,
        "status": 'Initiated'
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $http.post(SERVER_URL+'record/create', data).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Record Created');
    });
};
```

});

html code:

```
<form name="record" ng-submit="createNewRecord(record)">
        <div class="capainging-fields">
            <div class="col-md-6 input-feilds">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="Record-name">Record Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="record.name">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="email">Advertise:</label>
                    <select type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="record.advertiseId">
                        <option>test1</option>
                        <option>test2</option>
                        <option>test3</option>
                        <option>test4</option>
                        <option>test5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="email">Budget:</label>
                    <select type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="record.budget">
                        <option>test1</option>
                        <option>test2</option>
                        <option>test3</option>
                        <option>test4</option>
                        <option>test5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="email">Start Date:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp4" ng-model="record.startTime">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="email">End Date:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp5" ng-model="record.endTime">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-feilds">
                    <label for="email">Pricing Method:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="record.pricing">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="targetting">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="Targetting" class="target">Targeting:</label>
                    <div class="geography-container">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline geography" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#targetting-collapse"><input type="checkbox" value="">Geography</label>
                        <div id="targetting-collapse" class="collapse">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Country</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">States</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="devices">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline geography" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#devices-collapse"><input type="checkbox" value="">Devices</label>
                        <div id="devices-collapse" class="collapse">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">catgory1</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">catgory2</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">catgory3</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="browsers">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline geography" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#browsers-collapse"><input type="checkbox" value="">Browser</label>
                        <div id="browsers-collapse" class="collapse">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">catgory1</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">catgory2</label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">catgory3</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="days">
                        <div class="custome-day"><span>Day : </span></div>
                        <div class="week-days">
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info" id="fancy-checkbox-info" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        Sunday
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info" id="fancy-checkbox-info2" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info2" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info2" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        Monday
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info" id="fancy-checkbox-info3" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info3" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info3" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        Tuesday
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info" id="fancy-checkbox-info4" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info4" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info4" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        Wednesday
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info" id="fancy-checkbox-info5" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info5" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info5" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        Thursday
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info" id="fancy-checkbox-info6" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info6" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info6" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        Friday
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info" id="fancy-checkbox-info2" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info2" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info2" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        Saturday
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="time">
                        <div class="custome-day"><span>Time : </span></div>
                        <div class="week-days">
                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info-new" id="fancy-checkbox-info-new" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info-new" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info-new" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        15-7-2016 to 17-8-2016
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="[ form-group ]">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-info-secondrange" id="fancy-checkbox-info-secondrange" autocomplete="off" />
                                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info-secondrange" class="[ btn btn-info ]">
                                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                                        <span> </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-info-secondrange" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                                        12-7-2016 to 10-8-2016
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Record" />
    </form>
```

Now when I run file this, it generate pop-up 'Record Created' at page loading not when I clicked on button Create Campaign.

Please help guys. I want that it post my form data to server and controller should run onClick of create record.

Comment: I replicated it and its working fine. can you share the code with angular module and controller codes

Answer (score 0):

check in the controller maybe you call the function before clicking the submit button

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the code you have? If so, you miss a few things:

**A module** [(docs)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

And attaching the module to the DOM

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

**A Controller** [(docs)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) { ...  }
```

And attaching the controller to the DOM

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

---

I made a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q29hjfjt/1/) based on your code (including these modifications), and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3kKmSrAjZ52Rlz9KOGMO) here.

here is what i changed:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Create Record" ng-click="createNewRecord()" />
```

**createNewRecord** now gets the record models values and if you un-comment the post action then it should submit the data.